# @nestjs/graphql access to the playground

Tags: graphql, nestjs

I updated my version of @nest/graphql from 7.9.11 to 7.11.0 and now I have the following error :

```
src/app.module.ts:26:7 - error TS2345: Argument of type '{ path: string; autoSchemaFile: string; sortSchema: true; playground: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'GqlModuleOptions'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'playground' does not exist in type 'GqlModuleOptions'.

26       playground: true,
```

in my app module I have :

```
 GraphQLModule.forRoot({
      path: 'api/graphql',
      autoSchemaFile: join(process.cwd(), 'src/schema.gql'),
      sortSchema: true,
      playground: true,
    }),
```

And finally my package.json looks like this :

```
"dependencies": {
    "@instana/collector": "1.126.2",
    "@nestjs/common": "7.6.18",
    "@nestjs/config": "0.6.3",
    "@nestjs/core": "7.6.18",
    "@nestjs/graphql": "7.11.0",
    "@nestjs/passport": "7.1.5",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "7.6.18",
    "@nestjs/terminus": "7.2.0",
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "7.1.5",
    "apollo-server-express": "2.25.2",
    "cache-manager": "3.4.4",
    "cache-manager-redis-store": "2.0.0",
    "date-fns": "2.22.1",
    "graphql": "15.5.1",
    "graphql-tools": "7.0.5",
    "jwks-rsa": "1.12.3",
    "nestjs-pino": "1.4.0",
    "nestjs-redis": "1.3.3",
    "passport": "0.4.1",
    "passport-jwt": "4.0.0",
    "pg": "8.6.0",
    "pino-pretty": "5.1.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "6.6.7",
    "typeorm": "0.2.34"
  },
```

Comment: I had the same problem when updating to all latest versions, even newer than yours `"@nestjs/graphql": "^9.1.2"` and `"graphql-tools": "^8.2.0"`, what I found out is that the option of `playground: true` doesn't seem to exist anymore but if you remove it, you'll find out that Playground is still working fine without the option.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As @ghiscoding said in its comment, playground option doesn't exist in newer versions, but playground still working without it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).